# HIbernate[hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true] creating duplicate keys if older keys are deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hilo

I have hibernate application with GenerationType stratergy set to Auto.
allocation size is 50.
Property "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings set to "true"
it is using pooled optimizer .
so it started creating primary key ids with 1.
If in between any rows gets deleted , it starts sequence from low (-48 or -49) creates duplicate ids.

Any solution to avoid generating duplicate values.
Setting Property "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" to "false" solves problem but looking for any other solution.
Trying to understand behaviour.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.